# Yii правило валидации

Tags: php, yii

Система почему то отказывается показывать русское сообщение об ошибке.

Вот так прописано правило и при ошибке все равно выводится `Текст is too short (minimum is 1000 characters).`

```
public function rules()
{
    return array(
        array('text', 'length', 'min' => 1000, 'message' => 'Минимально допустимое количество символов 1000')
);
}
```

Comment: Если найдете, то отпишитесь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В `length`-валидаторе текст ошибок нужно задавать в свойствах `tooShort` (если меньше `min`) и `tooLong` (если больше `max`). Ошибка из `message` выведется только если проверяется точное кол-во символов заданное свойством `is`.

Смотрите [код проверки](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/master/framework/validators/CStringValidator.php#L77).

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте указать и максимальное количество символов. Вот пример, который работает:

```
array('name', 'length', 'min'=>4, 'max'=>250, 'message'=>'Количество символов должно быть от 4 до 250'),
```

А лучше смотрите в класс CStringValidator, он находится в

```
path/to/framework/validators/CStringValidator.php
```